# how to remove a node from nlb at runtime?

Tags: asp.net, nlb

i need to temporally exclude a node from an nlb.
May happen that a server is up and working but the web application i'm balancing is out of sinch with the same application in the others nodes.
Eg. some static variables are not the same of the same static variables of other nodes, because of a timeout, a write error and so on but the server is still working.
in this case i need to stop the server from nlb because the information in the web application is not in sinch with other nodes.
I need to prevent users from being serverd from this out to date server, untill it will became updated, but i need to do this programmatically
how can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control the NLB from the command line - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772833(v=ws.10).aspx

You can execute the tool using `Process.Start()` and pass in the relevant arguments.